# Error with parsing case sensitive fields in JSON data into columns in SQL server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have data with JSON value stored in a SQL DB column. I am trying to parse and get a few columns from the JSON value.
There are two specific values in the stored JSON column with the same name but one is capitalized and the other one isn't. They both represent two different values though.
Now while I parse data and save in view it is not allowing as SQL considers as the same name, even if I change the name of the column, it isn't reflecting the values it is supposed to, instead, it is giving the value of the other one on the same name.

here is my sample data

```
json = {"Deadline": "10-01-2020", "deadline": "11-01-2020"}
```

above json is a column in DB

This is my SQL query

```
select (Deadline, deadline)
from table_name
cross apply (json) with(Deadline datetime, deadline datetime)
```

This is not allowing as they are same name.

If I do

```
select (Deadline, deadline as Deadline2)
from table_name
cross apply (json) with(Deadline datetime, deadline datetime)
```

it is giving results of Deadline in Deadline2 but not deadline results

Answer (score 0):

Give them different names in the `WITH` clause:

```sql
DECLARE @JSON nvarchar(MAX) = '{"Deadline": "10-01-2020", "deadline": "11-01-2020"}';

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
     WITH(Deadline_PC datetime '$.Deadline',
          deadline_LC datetime '$.deadline');
```

Comment: Does this works the same with cross apply?
because JSON value comes from a column in the Table so I must use cross apply I believe.

I have tried working this way with cross apply, but it wasn't working for me

Comment: `APPLY` has nothing to do with it, @Hashtag, the solution is in the `WITH`. A `WITH` doesn't change how it operates depending on where `OPENJSON` is referenced in the `FROM`.

Comment: it doesn't seem to work as the names in JSON file has spaces in between

for example if i use deadline 2 instead of deadline in json =  '{"Deadline": "10-01-2020", "deadline 2": "11-01-2020"}'
it gives the below error 

```
JSON path is not properly formatted. Unexpected character ' ' is found
```
Is there a different way of handling this?

Comment: That wasn't the question you asked @Hashtag ... You asked about same names, different cases.

Comment: If, however, you have **invalid** JSON that isn't the fault of my solution, @Hashtag . You can't parse JSON if it's not properly formatted. You need to fix the JSON if it's malformed.

Comment: Well, I understand
Is there a way to deal with this space issue?

Comment: *"Is there a way to deal with this space issue?"* Yes, remove it. Fix the JSON.